# pdf background image does not fit on the page

Tags: html, css, printing, dinktopdf

I'm converting my **html** content to **pdf**, but it doesn't fully occupy the page **a4**. My **DPI** value is **96**. According to this dpi value, it should be **width:794px, height:1123px**, but when I do this, it takes up **half of the page** in width and almost **1/4** in height. how do i solve the problem?

```
#SC_Header {
            width: 794px;
            height: 1122px;
        }

        .scHeaderBG {
            background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/78/a5/da/78a5dac5e6b17cc75722b30c9bfa6df9.png');
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
<body>
<div id="main-content xSiyah">
    <section id="SC_Header" class="PageBreak break-after scHeaderBG">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12 text-center" style="text-align:center;">
                <img src="$$MemberImage$$" class="shadow-sm" style="width:220px; height:260px; position: relative; top: 752px" />
                <h3 class="Rb xTuruncu custom-title" style="position: relative; top: 380px;">$$NameSurname$$</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <p style="height:290px;"></p>
            <div class="col col-12 text-center" style="text-align:center; position:relative; left:600px; top:1230px;">
                <img src="$$CertificateQRCode$$" class="" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
                <p class="custom-text">Certificate Number: <strong>$$ApplicationNo$$</strong></p>
                <p class="custom-text">Issued Date: <strong>$$CourseEndDate$$</strong></p>
                <p class="custom-text">Expiry Date: <strong>$$ExpiryDate$$</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Sounds like there is confusion between printer dots and CSS pixels here. They aren’t the same. What are you using to do the conversion?

Comment: I am using the dinktopdf library when doing the conversion. So what path should I follow? @AHaworth